# NODE JS - TypeError: Path must be a string. Received { request

Tags: node.js, typescript, koa, koa2

Hello guys (and girls) ^^

I'm using koa2, koa-router, koa-static (try..) and no koa-send... but nothing work and i need your help. :D

So in fact, my js files are not find...
and i have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQUYY.png) ...

So i have installed koa-static and did this:

```
app.use(serve(__dirname + '/public'));
```

But a problem like this was appear :

```
koa deprecated Support for generators will been removed in v3. See the documentation for examples of how to convert old middleware //github.com/koajs/koa/tree/v2.x#old-signature-middleware-v1x server.js:18:5
```

I don't remember what i've tried but nothing worked... After 3 hours i've decided to change for koa-send !

So i install the new package and i code this from the example...

```
app.use(async function(ctx){
    await serve(ctx, ctx.path, { root: __dirname + '/public' });
});
```

and now i get ...

```
TypeError: Path must be a string. Received { request:
```

Thanks to stackoverflow to lock me with 2 links because of reputation....
so here the code of everything... http://pastebin.com/Gmvg5r9F

Someone have an idea please ? How can i make this functionnal ? I'm desperate... if you have the answer, please... ^_^

And happy new year everyone :p

EDIT : package.json if you need : "http:"//pastebin.com/cBg73WAF

EDIT²: Srsly, i've tried every package and nothing works... My project is actually blocked...

Comment: Someone can help me please ? I'm really desperate with this koa-send, static or whatever...

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are getting `koa deprecated Support for generators will been removed in v3. See the documentation` because you are using a `koa v2` with a `koa v1` "compatible" middleware but you can easily go around this using `koa-convert` to convert all `generator` based middlewares to the new `koa v2` async/await standards and use it without a problem.

**Example of koa convert**

```js
const convert = require('koa-convert');
app.use(convert(serve(__dirname + '/public')));
```

Lastly, I think you are facing that second error because you are using `serve` instead of `send` and that triggers the `koa-static` you just abandoned instead.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. I don't think my second error is because i've used "serve" instead of "send" because i just modify the name.
`import * as serve from "koa-send";` to save time I modify just static for send and vice versa

Comment: @Ravaniss ooh.. okay.

Have you tried doing some `console.logs` on what you are passing to make sure it is, in fact what you are looking for?

Also `path.join(__dirname, '/public')` ?

Comment: I'm getting error with koa-convert...

` UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejectio
n (rejecd: 1): Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
(node:164072) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are depreca
ted. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate
 the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.`

Comment: @Ravaniss i've updated my comment above.. ^ 


also you should update your question and include more code samples that you have on your code.

Comment: You have everything on the pastebin. And yes, the path is good with `path.join(__dirname, '/public');`
I've updated my code with this, more clear.